# Heatmap in d3.js/React.js - the rect element is not rendered in the graph

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to build a heat graph using d3 `data`, but it doesn't render all the squares:

```
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/heatmap_data.csv", function(data) {
   setState(data)
   svg.selectAll()
     .data(state, function(d){ return d.group+ ':' +d.variable ;})
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group) })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.variable) })
     .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
     .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
     .style("fill", 'red' )
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using?

Comment: Hi, michael again ;) 
I am using the latest version, 6.7.0
Well I tried it in many ways, it is rendering but it does not position itself as in the example, so my momentary solution was to use a different database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V6, `d3.csv` is implemented as a promise. Also, specify a correct selection for `selectAll` :

```
const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(null);

...

d3.scv('https://...').then(data => setGraphData(data));

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (graphData) {
    svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(graphData, d => `${d.group}:${d.variable}`)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      ...
  }
}, [graphData]);
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you so much!
I gonna try it